# SQL Server 2008 - How to show rows between 1001 to 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. With help of `TOP` clause in SQL Server I have run following query to display the first 1000 rows from my table Department

```
Select TOP 1000 * 
from Department;
```

Now I need to display the next 1000 data from the same table. Can anybody help me to find a solution for the this?

Comment: First of all, a `TOP` *without* an `ORDER BY` is pointless - what are you ordering by, to get the "top 1000" rows??? You need to decide which column to order by - **then** (and only then) does `TOP` make any sense

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER function to get the number of the row, and then take the numbers from X to Y. Below query is assuming that you want the results ordered by ID:

```
WITH OrderedDepartments AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM Department 
) 
SELECT ID, Name
FROM OrderedDepartments
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000;
```

Comment: If you want data to be listed in the specific order, you need to add this order to your query. In the mentioned query this was added in the  condition of row_number calculation (*`order by ID`*). Row_number function can't work without it. And in your query there's no guarantee that you will not receive the same row twice in different subsets.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_NAME) AS rownum
          FROM   DEPARTMENT
       ) AS t
WHERE  t.rownum BETWEEN 1001 AND 2001
```

Comment: This is the technique which was used in the SQL Server 2000 before the row_number was added...

Answer (score -1):

Best way is use "FETCH (Transact-SQL)", more info and sample available in following link,

[FETCH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The FETCH option relevant for cursors only.

Comment: FETCH option not relevant in this case as it is only applicable to cursors.